# exif-js not working anymore in laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, exif-js

I can't find a solution to this problem.
In laravel 5.2 all I needed was to install the npm package and then in app.js add this line:

```
window.EXIF = require('exif-js');
```

now in laravel 5.5 there's this new bootstrap.js file where you are supposed to put the same line. However doing so results in error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: EXIF is not defined`

I tried to mix the exif.js directly and load it in the page I am using and also set a `VAR EXIF = require('exif-js');` in the script but then I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: base64ToArrayBuffer is not defined`

I am out of ideas. Nothing works.

Comment: Just trying to undestand what you're doing. So you have `window.EXIF = require('exif-js');` in ./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js . right? that means you've installed laravel mix and you're using it, so what do you have in the webpack.mix.js file (which is in the project root folder)

Comment: I am mixing app.js there (which as far as I understand should get the exif.js and publish it in public/app.js)

Comment: And your app.js has this `require('./bootstrap');` ?

Comment: Exactly, it has that line.

Comment: If you open your browser console and type `EXIF` does it output anything or 'undefined' ?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: EXIF is not defined`

Comment: are you doing `npm run dev` everytime or have a `npm run watch`  on?

Comment: i'm using `npm run dev`. What I underdstand is that that `window.EXIF` line in bootstrap.js should instruct the framework that EXIF is needed globally. In 5.2 I didn't include app.js in my views and exif worked nonetheless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163435/discussion-between-sergio-reis-and-chriz74).